# Installing Elastic Apm Agent on Windows Server

Tags: elasticsearch, apm, elastic-apm

I've been trying to monitor my application which runs on Windows Server, it runs on .NET v.4.0
I want to implement Elastic Apm but on their documentation i only  saw  as guide for .NET 5 or higher versions. Is it possible to make it work on 4.0?